# how to rewrite wordpress media file (pdf) to php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm looking to re write files saved in my membersonly dir in wp-content/uploads so it redirects to a php file.

url to the file might be something like this
mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/membersonly/1234/myfile.pdf

rewrite to something like this
mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/membersonly/private_doc.php?file=myfile.pdf&postID=1234

original url format will always be membersonly/postid/filename  at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/membersonly/([^/]+)/(.+)$ wp-content/plugins/membersonly/private_doc.php?file=$2&postID=$1
```

Placed in your root `.htaccess` file.